# Visual Studio 2013 compile like visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have C++ VS2008 project and my lovely IDE VS13. How can I work into VS13, but compile and debug project like in would be VS08. When I open VS2008 *.sln files that wrote to me about one-way upgrade, and how you i guess you understand, project after open in vs2013 don't open in vs2008.

[image: http://s020.radikal.ru/i707/1505/6c/b51b6773cb43.jpg]

For now, I use VS13 like notepad then copy all files text to alt+tab opening VS 2008 IDE and there are run project. And again work in VS13.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Microsoft product lifecycle policies,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=Visual%20Studio&wa=wsignin1.0

Visual Studio 2008's mainstream support ended in April 2013, while Visual Studio 2013 was released in Jan 2014. That means Visual Studio 2013 will not support Visual Studio 2008 bits, so not a surprise if native multi targeting does not show v80.

I don't think you can easily get side by side, as VS2008 is too old, and its C++ project is not even MSBuild script. Once converted to VS2013, there is no way back.

Why cannot you just let VS2008 go? I guess that's why you get so many down votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert the solution to Visual Studio 2013 and still open it in Visual Studio 2008. You can, however, tell Visual Studio 2013 to use the Visual Studio 2008 compiler.

To do that, convert your solution to Visual Studio 2013 (don't forget to keep a copy of the original file, just in case), then open the project properties, go to the General options and select the Visual Studio 2008 *platform toolset*.

Comment: thank you, it's impossible - but your post give me idea to create two sln in project and alt+tab working

Comment: Why is that impossible?

Comment: into 2008 project to  platform toolset in properties and in 13 only 13/12/10 version is possible to set - no 2008 v80